# Why is this document rendered as XML not HTML5?

Tags: xml, html, lift

Why is the second document below renedered as XML not HTML? `document.constructor` becomes `XMLDocument`.

**EDIT** 
The Web server replies with `application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8` when I issue the request from the browser (instead of `curl`). I just noticed, when sniffing with Wireshark. Perhaps I need not have posted this question then, since it seems I have configured the Web server incorrectly.

**EDIT 2:** This was a Lift-Web issue (the Web framework I use). See my reply below.

---

(This breaks Google's SVG Web for me. SVG Web works fine, in my case, with HTML
but not XML. And I have no idea how to make the Web browser consider the
document being HTML not XML -- I think I have already specified that it is HTML not
XML.)

The *first* document below is rendered as HTML though. But I cannot for the life of me find
any relevant difference in the HTTP headers or `<meta>` tags of the first and second documents!?

(I've diffed them; there're only some uninteresting headers that differ.)

In particular, both documents specify `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`,
both in the HTTP headers and as `<meta>` tags.

(Does a browser check other stuff, in addition to the HTTP headers and  tags and perhaps file suffix, to derive the content type?)

When I debug some JavaScript code:
`document.constructor === XMLDocument` is true for the first document,
`document.constructor === HTMLDocument` is true for the second.

Browser: Google Chrome 9.0.597.83 beta.

Here follows the first document and its HTTP headers, as seen by `curl`: (this results in HTML)

```
$ curl -v -v http://localhost/foo/content-type-html-test.html | head -n10
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /foo/content-type-html-test.html HTTP/1.1
> ...
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 06 Mar 2011 09:06:42 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
< Last-Modified: Sun, 06 Mar 2011 08:58:30 GMT
< ETag: "77402b-3bc4-49dcc95441980"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 15300
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< 
...curl shows download progress...
* Closing connection #0
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:lift="http://liftweb.net/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
                <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
                <meta content="" name="description" />
                <meta content="" name="keywords" />
                <title>Foo</title>
                <!-- svg.js must the first script on the page. -->
                <script src="./content-type-html-test_files/svg.js" type="text/javascript" data-path="/classpath/js" ></script>
                <!--<script data-path="/classpath/js" type="text/javascript" src="/classpath/js/svg.js"></script> -->
                <script src="./content-type-html-test_files/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

The second: (results in XML)

```
$ curl -v -v http://localhost:8080/0/about.html | head -n10
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /0/about.html HTTP/1.1
> ...
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Expires: Sun, 6 Mar 2011 09:07:35 UTC
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1p9o4y4cv2d531as8s5xrdysch;Path=/
< Content-Length: 11085
< Cache-Control: no-cache; private; no-store
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Sun, 6 Mar 2011 09:07:35 UTC
< X-Lift-Version: 2.2
< Server: Jetty(6.1.25)
< 
...curl shows download progress...
* Closing connection #0
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:lift="http://liftweb.net/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
                <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
                <meta content="" name="description" />
                <meta content="" name="keywords" />
                <title>Foo</title>
                <!-- svg.js must the first script on the page. -->
                <script src="/classpath/js/svg.js" type="text/javascript" data-path="/classpath/js"></script> 
                <!--<script data-path="/classpath/js" type="text/javascript" src="/classpath/js/svg.js"></script> -->
```

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Are you using HTML5 intentionally?

Comment: Hi Jaroslav: Yes and yes. Firefox also interprets the document as XML. Opera as HTML. --- However! I recently sniffed with Wireshark, and noticed that my Web server replied: application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8. Perhaps the browser sends some headers (e.g. Accept and User-Agent) that causes the Web server to behave differntly. So the results from `curl` are probably misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the Web server sends HTML not XHTML to all browsers. The Web framework I use is Lift-Web  and I had to add this line to Lift-Web's Boot.scala:

```
LiftRules.htmlProperties.default.set(
        (r: Req) => new Html5Properties(r.userAgent))
```

as described here: http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/HtmlProperties_XHTML_and_HTML5

(And here are some more things I think you also need to do: http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Setting_the_DocType )

The server now says
`Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`
instead of 
`application/xml`.
So now the document renders as HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

I read your question this morning and couldn't see what the problem was, but now I've seen your edit I think I know what it is.  This is what a typical request looks like in Firefox (using [LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/)):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.14) Gecko/20110301 Fedora/3.6.14-1.fc14 Firefox/3.6.14
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
```

Note the line `Accept:`.  I suspect your server is sending `text/html` to curl because it's not explicitly declaring that it can support `application/xhtml+xml`.  Since Firefox (and presumably other browsers that are not IE) do declare support for it, the server sends with that content type.

Note that this is normally a completely reasonable thing for a web server to do, so not really a configuration error, but I would suggest the solution is to configure Jetty to always send as `text/html` no matter what the `Accept:` header on the request says.

Comment: Hi robertc! Thanks for the info on Curl and Firefox. The Web framework I use is Lift-Web actually (written the Scala programming language). Lift-Web comes with an embedded Jetty server. I have added a few lines that makes Lift-Web send HTML not XHTML; see my reply.